# Press "enter" to submit form doesn't work (js)

Tags: javascript, google-gadget

i'm using google gadget to write a short script and try to insert to google site. 
When user press <kbd>Go</kbd> button, javascript function is triggered and everything works fine, but when user press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, error occurs:

```
Missing or malformed url parameter
```

I'm not sure it's caused by my code or google gadget/site.

My html code:

```
<form name="theform">
<input type="text" size="20" id="search"/> 
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Go!" ONCLICK="GotoURL(this.form)">
</form>
```

javascript function

```
function GotoURL(dl) { 

var mySearch = document.getElementById("search").value;
url='some_url'+mySearch;
window.open(url,'_blank');
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `onsubmit` event on the form instead of the `onclick` event of the button:

```
<form name="theform" onsubmit="GotoURL(this)">
    <input type="text" size="20" id="search"/> 
    <input type="submit" value="Go!">
</form>
```

Make sure that the `GotoURL()` function returns `false` to prevent the form from actually submitting.

Comment: Hi @Elian, it works! but it still show the error after new tab open (previously, it just shows the error without open new tab). I've add "return false;" at the end of GotoURL function. have any idea on this? thanks

Comment: @Mario - Are you sure that the generated url is valid? Do you url-encode your querystring parameters?

Comment: hi @ElianEbbing, i just encode the url. nothing change. the error is still there. is it caused by form submission? Previously, press "go" button got no error, but press "enter" cannot open new tab and just show error msg. Now, press "go" button or press "enter", both can open new tab but both show error msg.

Comment: @Mario - Maybe you should try `onsubmit="return GotoURL(this);"`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an `onsubmit` handler to the `form` tag itself: `<form onsubmit="GotoURL(this)">`